# Api Platform Security - How to give access to an object to a dynamic group of users?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

We have an object with many owners, stored in an ArrayCollection(). Is there any way to implement a security policy in Api Platform, so only these users have access? So far, I've tested and it seems there's no way to do this with access control expressions, as these do not support ArrayCollection, but only a simple array (e.g., 'user in object.owners' does not work). This seems like a very straightforward and popular use case, do you have an idea how we can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be custom voters. From API Platform's docs:

> The easiest and recommended way to hook custom access control logic is
>   to write Symfony Voter classes. Your custom voters will automatically
>   be used in security expressions through the is_granted() function.
>
> In order to give the current object to your voter, use the expression
>   is_granted('READ', object)